# how to access webcam using angular 6 cordova mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, angular6, hybrid-mobile-app

How to wrap an Angular app with Apache Cordova camera.
whether i have to install Cordova plugin or npm angular plugin.
please give some reference links.

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

npm i cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: Hi Ezhil! I'm not quiet sure what your question is here. In case you install cordova-plugin-camera, you'd use it according to the documentation which is available in the plugins repository (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_camera) e.g. `navigator.camera.getPicture(...)`. Since it is a cordova plugin, you install it using `cordova plugin add` and not `npm i`.